# Split a table in two (I have table and tabular) in latex

Tags: tables

I know that there exists similar questions like mine. However, I can not split my table.

My goal is to maintain the headnote on the second page.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:table-1}Banking, Currency and Sovereign crises dates.}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Countries       & Banking    & Currency   & Sovereign \\ \hline
Albania     & 1994       & 1997 & 1990      \\
Algeria     & 1990       & 1988, 1994 &      \\
Argentina     & 2001       & 1975, 1981, 1987, 2002, 2013  & 2014     \\
Armenia   & 1994       &  &      \\
Austria  & 2008       &  &      \\
Bangladesh   & 1987       & 1976 &      \\
Belarus   & 1995       & 1997, 2009, 2015  &      \\
Belgium   & 2008       &  &      \\
Benin   & 1988       &  1994 &      \\
Bulgaria   & 1996       & 1996 & 1990      \\
Burkina Faso   & 1990       & 1994 &       \\
Burundi  & 1994      &  &      \\
Cambodia   &        & 1971,1992 &       \\
Cameroon   & 1987,1995       & 1994 &  1989     \\
Chile   & 1976, 1981       & 1972, 1982 & 1983      \\
China   & 1998       &  &      \\
Colombia   & 1982, 1998       & 1985 &       \\
Croatia     & 1998      &     &       \\
Czech Republic        & 1996 &       &           \\
Denmark & 2008 &            &           \\
Egypt, Arab Rep.     & 1980      & 1979, 1990, 2016  & 1984      \\
El Salvador     & 1989      & 1986 &      \\
Estonia   & 1992       & 1992 &      \\
Ethiopia   &       & 1993 &       \\
Finland   & 1992       & 1993 &    \\
France  & 2008       &  &      \\
Greece   & 2008       & 1983 &  2012    \\
Guinea     & 1985, 1993      & 1982, 2005  & 1985     \\
Honduras        &  & 1990      &      1981     \\
Hungary & 1991, 2008 &            &           \\
India     & 1993   & &    \\
Indonesia    & 1997    &1979, 1998 & 1999     \\
Ireland     & 2008       &  &       \\
Israel   & 1983      & 1975, 1980, 1985 &      \\
Italy  & 2008       &  1981 &      \\
Jordan   & 1989     & 1989 & 1989     \\
 Korea, Rep.   & 1997      & 1998  &      \\
Kyrgyz Republic  & 1995       & 1997 &      \\
Lao PDR   &       &  1972, 1978, 1986, 1997 &      \\
Latvia & 1995, 2008      & 1992 &    \\
Lesotho   &    & 1985, 2015  &       \\
Lithuania  & 1995       & 1992  &      \\
Madagascar  & 1988      & 1984, 1994, 2004  & 1981     \\
Malawi   &       & 1994, 2012  &    1982   \\
Malaysia   & 1997      & 1998 &     \\
Mali & 1987      & 1994  &      \\
Mauritania   & 1984      & 1993 &       \\
Mexico   & 1981, 1994      & 1977, 1982, 1995  & 1982      \\
Moldova        & 2014 & 1999       &     2002      \\
Mongolia   & 2008 &    1990, 1997         &           \\
Morocco   & 1980     & 1981 & 1983     \\
Mozambique     & 1987      &  1987, 2015 &  1984    \\
Nepal   & 1988       & 1984, 1992 &     \\
Netherlands    & 2008       &  &       \\
North Macedonia  & 1993      &  &       \\
Norway & 1991       &  &      \\
Panama   & 1988       &  &       1983   \\
Peru     & 1983      & 1976, 1981, 1988  & 1978       \\
Philippines        & 11983, 1997  & 1983, 1998       &     1983     \\
Poland & 1992 &            &    1981       \\
Portugal & 2008     &  1983 &      \\
Romania   & 1998      & 1996 &     1982  \\
Russian Federation  &1998, 2008        & 1998, 2014  & 1998      \\
Slovenia      & 1992, 2008  &     &           \\
Spain & 1977, 2008 &    1983        &           \\
Sweden   & 1991, 2008     & 1993 &     \\
Switzerland     & 2008       &  &      \\
Syrian Arab Republic  &     & 1988 &      \\
Tajikistan   &      & 1999, 2015  &       \\
Tanzania & 1987     & 1985, 1990 & 1984      \\
Thailand & 1983, 1997      & 1998 &      \\
Togo  & 1993      & 1994 &    1979   \\
Tunisia     & 1991     &  &        \\
Uganda       & 1994 & 1980, 1988    &  1981         \\
Ukraine & 1998, 2008, 2014  &   1998, 2009, 2014 & 1998, 2009, 2014 \\
United Kingdom  & 2007      &  &    \\
United States  & 1988, 2007   &  &       \\
Uruguay    & 1981, 2002   & 1972, 1983, 1990, 2002  & 1983, 2002      \\
Uzbekistan       &     & 2000    &           \\
Vietnam & 1997 &    1972, 1981, 1987        &  1985         \\
              &            &            &          
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Also if possible I would like to size my table to fit in the page.

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.  You can use `longtable` in order to allow a table to occupy more than one page.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{llll}
\caption{\label{tab:table-1}Banking, Currency and Sovereign crises dates.}\\
\toprule
Countries            & Banking           & Currency                      &  Sovereign  \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{\label{tab:table-1}Banking, Currency and Sovereign crises dates. - continued form previous page}\\
\toprule
Countries            & Banking           & Currency                      &  Sovereign \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
Albania              & 1994              & 1997                          & 1990             \\
Algeria              & 1990              & 1988, 1994                    &                  \\
Argentina            & 2001              & 1975, 1981, 1987, 2002, 2013  & 2014             \\
Armenia              & 1994              &                               &                  \\
Austria              & 2008              &                               &                  \\ \addlinespace
Bangladesh           & 1987              & 1976                          &                  \\
Belarus              & 1995              & 1997, 2009, 2015              &                  \\
Belgium              & 2008              &                               &                  \\
Benin                & 1988              &  1994                         &                  \\
Bulgaria             & 1996              & 1996                          & 1990             \\ \addlinespace
Burkina Faso         & 1990              & 1994                          &                  \\
Burundi              & 1994              &                               &                  \\
Cambodia             &                   & 1971,1992                     &                  \\
Cameroon             & 1987, 1995        & 1994                          & 1989             \\
Chile                & 1976, 1981        & 1972, 1982                    & 1983             \\ \addlinespace
China                & 1998              &                               &                  \\
Colombia             & 1982, 1998        & 1985                          &                  \\
Croatia              & 1998              &                               &                  \\      
Czech Republic       & 1996              &                               &                  \\
Denmark              & 2008              &                               &                  \\ \addlinespace
Egypt, Arab Rep.     & 1980              & 1979, 1990, 2016              & 1984             \\
El Salvador          & 1989              & 1986                          &                  \\
Estonia              & 1992              & 1992                          &                  \\
Ethiopia             &                   & 1993                          &                  \\
Finland              & 1992              & 1993                          &                  \\ \addlinespace
France               & 2008              &                               &                  \\
Greece               & 2008              & 1983                          & 2012             \\
Guinea               & 1985, 1993        & 1982, 2005                    & 1985             \\
Honduras             &                   & 1990                          & 1981             \\
Hungary              & 1991, 2008        &                               &                  \\ \addlinespace
India                & 1993              &                               &                  \\
Indonesia            & 1997              & 1979, 1998                    & 1999             \\
Ireland              & 2008              &                               &                  \\
Israel               & 1983              & 1975, 1980, 1985              &                  \\ 
Italy                & 2008              & 1981                          &                  \\ \addlinespace
Jordan               & 1989              & 1989                          & 1989             \\
Korea, Rep.          & 1997              & 1998                          &                  \\
Kyrgyz Republic      & 1995              & 1997                          &                  \\
Lao PDR              &                   & 1972, 1978, 1986, 1997        &                  \\
Latvia               & 1995, 2008        & 1992                          &                  \\ \addlinespace
Lesotho              &                   & 1985, 2015                    &                  \\
Lithuania            & 1995              & 1992                          &                  \\
Madagascar           & 1988              & 1984, 1994, 2004              & 1981             \\
Malawi               &                   & 1994, 2012                    & 1982             \\
Malaysia             & 1997              & 1998                          &                  \\ \addlinespace
Mali                 & 1987              & 1994                          &                  \\
Mauritania           & 1984              & 1993                          &                  \\
Mexico               & 1981, 1994        & 1977, 1982, 1995              & 1982             \\
Moldova              & 2014              & 1999                          & 2002             \\
Mongolia             & 2008              & 1990, 1997                    &                  \\ \addlinespace
Morocco              & 1980              & 1981                          & 1983             \\
Mozambique           & 1987              & 1987, 2015                    & 1984             \\
Nepal                & 1988              & 1984, 1992                    &                  \\
Netherlands          & 2008              &                               &                  \\
North Macedonia      & 1993              &                               &                  \\ \addlinespace
Norway               & 1991              &                               &                  \\
Panama               & 1988              &                               & 1983             \\
Peru                 & 1983              & 1976, 1981, 1988              & 1978             \\
Philippines          & 1983, 1997        & 1983, 1998                    & 1983             \\
Poland               & 1992              &                               & 1981             \\ \addlinespace
Portugal             & 2008              & 1983                          &                  \\
Romania              & 1998              & 1996                          & 1982             \\
Russian Federation   & 1998, 2008        & 1998, 2014                    & 1998             \\
Slovenia             & 1992, 2008        &                               &                  \\
Spain                & 1977, 2008        & 1983                          &                  \\ \addlinespace
Sweden               & 1991, 2008        & 1993                          &                  \\
Switzerland          & 2008              &                               &                  \\
Syrian Arab Republic &                   & 1988                          &                  \\ 
Tajikistan           &                   & 1999, 2015                    &                  \\
Tanzania             & 1987              & 1985, 1990                    & 1984             \\ \addlinespace
Thailand             & 1983, 1997        & 1998                          &                  \\
Togo                 & 1993              & 1994                          & 1979             \\
Tunisia              & 1991              &                               &                  \\ 
Uganda               & 1994              & 1980, 1988                    & 1981             \\
Ukraine              & 1998, 2008, 2014  & 1998, 2009, 2014              & 1998, 2009, 2014 \\ \addlinespace
United Kingdom       & 2007              &                               &                  \\
United States        & 1988, 2007        &                               &                  \\
Uruguay              & 1981, 2002        & 1972, 1983, 1990, 2002        & 1983, 2002       \\
Uzbekistan           &                   & 2000                          &                  \\
Vietnam              & 1997              &    1972, 1981, 1987           & 1985             \\         
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]